# A question about "construction by induction".

Tags: real-analysis, induction

In Rudin's principle of mathematical analysis or other books, they often write that pick $x_1$ and suppose we have chosen $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$, then choose $x_{n+1}$, and says by induction, we have construct a sequence $\{x_n \}_{n=1}^\infty$

For example, if I want to prove: Let $X$ be a metric space and $K \subseteq X$. If every infinite subset of $K$ has an accumulation point in $K$, then $K$ is totally bounded.

Prove it by contradiction. $\exists r \gt0$ s.t. $K$ can not be covered by finitely many open balls centered in $K$ with radius $r$.

Choose an arbitrary point $x_1\in K$, then $K$ can not be covered by $B(x_1,r)$. So $$\exists x_2\in K-B(x_1,r)$$ and $K$ can not be covered by $$B(x_1,r)\cup B(x_2,r)$$

Suppose we have choose $x_1,\dots x_n$, hence $K$ can not be covered by $$B(x_1,r)\cup \dots \cup B(x_n,r)$$, choosing $$x_{n+1}\in K- \Bigl( B(x_1,r)\cup \dots \cup B(x_n,r) \Bigr)$$

By inaction, we have constructed a sequence $\{x_n \}_{n=1}^\infty$ in $K$ s.t. $$x_i\neq x_j  \;\;\forall i\neq j \text{ and } d(x_i,x_j)\geqslant r $$ , then $\dots \dots$ (skip the whole proof)

If I want to write it more formally, let $$S=\{n \in N \;| \; \{x_k \}_{k=1}^n\in K \text{ such that } d(x_i,x_j)\geqslant r\;\; \forall i\neq j \text{ and } x_k\in K- \Bigl( B(x_1,r)\cup \dots \cup B(x_{k-1},r) \Bigr) \} \;\;\;\color{red}{(\star)}$$

First, choosing an arbitrary point $x_1\in K$. Suppose we have chosen $\{ x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}\}$ satisfying that $$d(x_i,x_j)\geqslant r \;\; \forall i\neq j \text{ and } x_k\in K- \Bigl( B(x_1,r)\cup \dots \cup B(x_{k-1},r) \Bigr)\text{, }\forall k=1,\dots,n-1$$

Now, choose $$x_n \in K- \Bigl( B(x_1,r)\cup \dots \cup B(x_{n-1},r) \Bigr)$$, then $$d(x_n,x_k)\geqslant r \;\;\forall k=1,\dots,n-1$$

Hence, $S=\Bbb N$, which means $\{x_n \}_{n=1}^\infty$ is constructed and $d(x_i,x_j)\geqslant r \;\; \forall i\neq j$

$\color{blue}{\textrm{My question :}}$ I thinks the set $S$ in $\color{red}{(\star)}$ for induction looks weird, since I have never write this for construction. Could someone help me to write it more formally, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More formally, the kind of construction you're outlining actually boils down to a combination of an application of the Axiom of Choice and a construction by recursion.

In particular, one of the formulations of the Axiom of Choice is: for every set $K$, there is a function $c : P(K) \setminus \{ \emptyset \} \to K$ such that for every $S \subseteq K$ with $S \ne \emptyset$, we have $c(S) \in S$.  Now, suppose we choose such a function $c$ (where this "choose" is actually not a reference to the Axiom of Choice, it stands for an application of the formal proof rule of existence elimination, $\exists E$).  Then under the given hypotheses, we can recursively construct a sequence where $x_n = c\left( K \setminus \bigcup_{i < n} B(x_i, r) \right)$.

---

To illustrate the gap in the argument you're trying to make, it does not follow just from the fact that a finite sequence of any arbitrary length exists satisfying some property that an infinite sequence exists satisfying that property.  For example, in $\mathbb{N}$, for any $k$ there exists a finite sequence in $\mathbb{N}$ of length $k$ which is strictly decreasing -- namely $(k, k-1, k-2, \ldots, 2, 1)$.  However, it does not follow from this that there exists an infinite sequence in $\mathbb{N}$ which is strictly decreasing -- which does not exist since $\mathbb{N}$ is well-ordered.

Comment: Do we really need axiom of choice. Will the following not do:
$$f(1) = x_1 \\
\text{for }n > 1, f_n(i)=
                  \begin{cases}
                   f_{n-1}(i), & 1 \leq i \leq n-1 \\
                   \exists x_n \in K-\bigcup_1^{n-1}B_r(x_i),f_n(n)=x_n
                  \end{cases}$$

Define $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow X$ by $f(n)=f_n(n)$

Comment: Yes, we really need at least some form of the axiom of choice.  What you write doesn't even make sense really, since $\exists x_n \in K \ldots$ does not define a value.  (You might also be interested in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_dependent_choice - where the version in terms of "pruned trees with $\omega$ levels" would also be usable to formalize this proof.  I chose not to mention that in the main answer as I decided it would be more for a dedicated set theory course than for a real analysis course.)

Answer (score 1):

You have assumed that $K$ is not totally bounded, and that a suitable $r>0$ is fixed.

Define a set $S =$

$$\{n \geq 1 : \text{it is possible to select $n$ distinct elements of $K$}$$

$$ \text{ such that $d(x_i,\,x_j) \geq r$ for any choices with $i \neq j$.}    \}$$

I say that you have proved already that $S \,=\, \{1,2,3,4,\dots\}$.

Did you prove that $1$ belongs to $S$? Yes.

Did you prove that $n = k +1$ belongs to $S$ for any $k \geq 1$, under that assumption that $\{1,2,\dots,k\} \subset S$? Yes.

Comment: That does not quite do it. This induction, as stated, does not imply the existence of a single sequence $(x_n)_{n \ge 1}$ satisfying $d(x_i,x_j) \ge r$ for all $i,j \in \mathbb N$; it only implies the existence of a sequence of finite sequences each satisfying that property.

Comment: i see your point. It seems the connection between recursion and induction, even though both countable, is not so clear as I had supposed. for example:   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1582154/being-explicit-with-recursion-in-a-basic-proof

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_1$ be an arbitrary point of $X$. Define $f_n:[1,n] \cap \mathbb{N} \rightarrow X$ by

$$f(1) = x_1 \\
\text{for }n > 1, f_n(i)=
                  \begin{cases}
                   f_{n-1}(i), & 1 \leq i \leq n-1 \\
                   \exists x_n \in K-\bigcup_1^{n-1}B_r(x_i),f_n(n)=x_n
                  \end{cases} \\
$$

Define $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow X$ by $f(n)=f_n(n)$.